# Dudas con el header Location de PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo una base de datos en esa base de datos tengo un atributo llamado url donde se guardan las url de cada pagina..

Lo que quiero sabes y si es que se puede es poner esa url en el Header

Ejemplo.

```
$Url=$fetched_row['Url'];

header("Location:$Url");
```

Quisiera saber si se puede y como es el codigo.
Saludos...

Comment: si se puede y es así como lo pusiste, bueno debe de ser doble comilla como lo edite , si lo pones sencillo no tomara el valor de la variable

Comment: Pero lo he usado y me marca como que busca una pagina llamada $Url

Comment: si necesitas comillas dobles así como lo edite, o puedes concatenarlo con punto 'Location:'.$Url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utiliza **urlencode** seria algo como:

```
$Url=urlencode($fetched_row['Url']);

header("Location:$Url");
```